# Custom progres bar андроид

Tags: android, android-animation

Как можно сделать такой progres bar, только с футбольным мячиком и вместо того что бы он вечно прыгал, скользил в горизонтальном направлении, и допустим раз в 2 секунды подпрыгивал     [image: Мячик]

Comment: Курите: https://developer.android.com/training/animation/, но это занимает не мало времени

Answer (score 0):

Не могу спокойно реагировать, когда человек вместо 4 слов в гугл - "android custom progres bar", которые дадут [вот это](http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/views/progressbar.php), умудрился написать на сюда вопрос на 30 слов и прикрутить гифку... Это удручает =( Не поймите неправильно, я просто слишком ленив чтоб задать на стэковерфлоу вопрос и ждать ответа, когда даже не попытался его загуглить и получить результат мгновенно

Comment: я задал вопрос, с надеждой что кто-то делал, что-то подобное,и имеет пример кода, спасибо за ответ:)

Comment: С такой надеждой надо сначала гуглить) Если пример кода есть - он с высокой вероятностью нагуглится быстрее, что мы и наблюдаем. Не говоря уже о правилах нашего дружного сообщества)

Comment: тогда прошу прощения:)

Comment: Да было б за что, главное чтоб делались выводы и программист развивался)